# Dynamically add projects to maven build reactor?

Tags: java, plugins, maven, code-generation

I wrote a maven plugin that generates Java source code based on some definition language.
The generated source code should be split up into several jar files (interfaces, implementation, etc.).
I would like to build my project containing the definition language together with the generated sources but I'm not sure what the best way is.
I thought of extending my maven plugin to generate for each jar a new maven project and add them dynamically to the current running maven build reactor.

*Is it possible to add new maven projects to the build reactor while the build is running?* or *Could I generate new maven projects while maven is parsing the directory structure for building the reactor? (Maybe in the `validate` phase?)*

Does anyone have a better idea how to compile the generated maven projects in the same reactor?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally, i would recommend just using one project with multiple artifacts

- generate the sources
- compile all the sources
- use multiple assembly plugin configs to split the resulting class files into multiple jars

i believe you could generate these various jars with different classifiers and then depend on them as independent resources in other maven modules/projects.